# iOS get NSDate from string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I want to convert string **Thu, Nov 22, 2012** to `NSDate`.

I've tried this:

```
NSString *str = @"Thu, Nov 22, 2012";

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE,MMM dd yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"date: %@",date);
```

But i'm getting null.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I think you forget the ',' in date format string. `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE,MMM dd, yyyy"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the correct format letters, you just need to fix commas (and spacing) like that:

`EEE, MMM dd, yyyy` although one E would even be enough (E, MMM dd, yyyy).

See the [format reference](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: +1 for the nice answer and new information (one E would even be enough)

Comment: also even for year value one 'y' would be enough check this nice article http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/nsdateformatter-formatting-strings-reference/

Comment: @Blios: Yes, for parsing it is the same. When creating a string it's different. Year 10 e.g. will be 0010 with `yyyy` and only 10 with `y`. Check the link in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

`NSString` `date` `format` and `NSDateFormatter` should be `same`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *string = @"Thu, Nov 22, 2012";

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE,MMM dd, yyyy"]; //your date formatter is not correct

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: sorry for this time, Jaydee3 is right, we need to fix spacing and commas.